# Verification header bad idea for encryption?

Tags: encryption, blowfish, encryption-symmetric

I'm using encryption (blowfish symmetric) to send a packet.  Is it a bad idea from a security point of view to have a header at the beginning of the packet (that is also encrypted with the rest of the packet) that I can use to verify the packet is valid?

Pseudo code example:

```
byte[] verificationHeader = [1,2,3,4,5];
receive(packet);
unencrypt(packet);
if (packet.getData().beginswith(verificationHeader)) {
   // assume packet is good, try to do something with it
} else {
   // drop packet
}
```

I want to verify it because any other application could be broadcasting in my group and I don't want to get mixed up with other stuff.

Could it potentially help a hacker decrypt my packet?

If it is a bad idea then can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in theory, it's a pretty bad idea -- it gives somebody doing a brute-force attack a known "target", so when/if they get the right key the know it (and quickly at that).

At least from a viewpoint of security, it would be much better to leave that part in plaintext. It might be more practical as well -- it saves you from decrypting something if it's not going to be useful anyway.

Comment: But if the hacker was to put the verification into a packet and the rest of the packet was garbage my code would be trying to do something with it...  and that would be bad

Comment: @JackAllan: It sounds like what you're after is a message authentication code (MAC). I'm pretty sure Googling should turn up some reasonably safe ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it bad idea or not, but if you decide it is then maybe you could send a random number, followed by the random number or'ed with the header. then on the other side you or that number with the random number again. Then you aren't sending the same thing a bunch of times, but it is all encrpyted so it isn't hackable. I think my math is right, but the idea holds anyway.

```
ie
value = random | header;
send (random, value);
header = random | value;
```